# not access my page without using main page , redirect them back when they do

Tags: javascript, php

[my sample pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgfF9.jpg)

i had a main page (folder:directory index.php ) it will send ajax request to get other folder index page and return to the main page and so the other 2 folder map inside directory folder.

i got not problem with ajax request but i dont want user to access the page without using my main page , so when they type **domain.com/directory/company/** in url , i want to redirect them back to main page.

how do i make the page check like this

```
if(ajax request){

//process normally.

}else if(access without using main page){

//redirect back to main page.
}
```

i just dont want them to access my page without using main page , redirect them back when they do, how do i achieve that ? so how combine php and js ?

Comment: You can try setting cookies/sessions

Comment: You can also use a PHP Session check, which is created on your main page.